App Store Connect, 'next' button is grayed out when adding new bank account even though all information is correct
I am trying to add my bank account to app store connect, but even if I enter all my information correctly or incorrectly, the button remains greyed out.


I tried it with 4 different bank information.
I tried different browsers and different computers.
I created a support ticket, but no response yet.

Are there any other people encountering this problem?

Having the same issue

Apple expects a slightly different format for the Transit Number (or Bank Code).
The UI does not make this very clear. In Canada, we have a bank-specific institution number and a transit number based on the location where the account was opened. I kept trying to add the transit number, but Apple expects the transit number to be prefixed with the institution number. Additionally, they want a specific format. For example, my institution number is 003, but they only accept 0003.
So, my code was 0003XXXXX, where XXXXX is my transit number.
This will be different for each country, but the best way is to click on the Don't know your transit number? link (or your specific Don't know ... link) and search for your bank. You will see the expected format under the Routing #.

Once the correct code is accepted, the Bank Address will display below the form, and the 'Next' button will be active.


Thank you for the detailed information you provided for those experiencing this problem.

The problem was in the Bank Code/Branch Code. As a response when I contacted Apple:
00XX X000X XXX
It gave a code like this. It will probably tell you this when you contact the bank and ask for the bank code and branch code.

I am having the same issue. Whats bank code here ?
